# Vigenere Cipher java UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, utf8-decode, vigenere

Hello evrybody who reads this!

I need to realize Vigenere cipher on Java.
I have a .txt document, which I'm going to read, encode and decode. Here it is:

```
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好
```

My problem is that I don't know how to shift chars correctly, According to [this table](http://unicode-table.com/ru/) latin letters have codes from 0061 to 007A. German ones that I need: 00C0 - 00FF, polish: 0100-017F, russian 0430-044F and I didn't gind chineese.

How can I specify `unshiftChar` and `shiftChar` to make it correst?
Now my input looks like this:

```
The original text from file is: 
﻿ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好 

String that will be encoded is: 
asciiabcdexyzgermanäöüäöüßpolishąęźżńłrussianабвгдежэюяcjk你好

The encrypted string is: 
äckkwdfaqmzjökcbucäbdslhwfssjvåjoxfbsltfvwgnvboegbrnboeghxöb

The decrypted phrase is: 
asciiab￥dexyzg￧rmanäö￷äöuupo￮ibmjcå￷äldhtc￲iwmtdå￶awmtdd￼pw
```

Here is a Java code:

```
    public class VigenereCipher 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String key = "Unicode";

        File file = new File("G:\\unicode.txt");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] fileBArray = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(fileBArray);

        String text = new String(fileBArray, "UTF-8");

        //String text = "Some simple text to check the decoding algorythm";
        System.out.println("The original text from file is: \n" + text);
        String enc = encrypt(text, key);
        System.out.println(enc + "\n");
        System.out.println("The decrypted phrase is: ");
        System.out.println(decrypt(enc, key));
    }

    // Encrypts a string
    public static String encrypt(String message, String key) 
    {
        message = StringToLowerCaseWithAllSymbols(message);
        System.out.println("String that will be encoded is: \n" + message);
        char messageChar, keyChar;
        String encryptedMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) 
        {
            messageChar = shiftChar(message.charAt(i));
            keyChar = shiftChar(key.charAt(i % key.length()));
            messageChar = (char) ((keyChar + messageChar) % 29);
            messageChar = unshiftChar(messageChar);
            encryptedMessage += messageChar;
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe encrypted string is: ");
        return encryptedMessage;
    }

    // Decrypts a string
     public static String decrypt(String cipher,String key)
     {
            char cipherChar, keyChar;
            cipher = StringToLowerCaseWithAllSymbols(cipher);
            String decryptedMessage = "";
            cipher = cipher.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < cipher.length(); i++) 
            {
                cipherChar = shiftChar(cipher.charAt(i));
                keyChar = shiftChar(key.charAt(i % key.length()));
                cipherChar = (char) ((29 + cipherChar - keyChar) %  29);
                cipherChar = unshiftChar(cipherChar);
                decryptedMessage += cipherChar;
            }
            return decryptedMessage;
     }

     // Prunes all characters not in the alphabet {A-Öa-ö} from a string and changes it to all lower     case.
     public static String StringToLowerCaseWithAllSymbols(String s) 
     {
            //s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zåäöÅÄÖ]", "");
            // 's' contains all the symbols from my text
            s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zäöüÄÖÜßąęźżńłабвгдежэюя你好]", "");
            return s.toLowerCase();
        }

    // Assigns characters a,b,c...å,ä,ö the values 1,2,3...,26,28,29.
     private static char shiftChar(char c) 
     {
            if (96 < c && c < 123) 
            {
                c -= 97;
            } 
            else if (c == 229) 
            {
                c = 26;
            } 
            else if (c == 228) 
            {
                c = 27;
            } 
            else if (c == 246) 
            {
                c = 28;
            }
            return c;
        }

    // Undoes the assignment in shiftChar and gives the characters back their UTF-8 values. 
     private static char unshiftChar(char c) 
     {
            if (0 <= c && c <= 25) 
            {
                c += 97;
            } 
            else if (c == 26) 
            {
                c = 229;
            } 
            else if (c == 27) 
            {
                c = 228;
            } 
            else if (c == 28) 
            {
                c = 246;
            }
            return c;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't want to shift:  You want to *rotate*.  Suppose we're working with the English alphabet.  If 'A'+2 is 'C', what's 'Z'+2?  When you're implementing a Vigenere cipher, you want 'Z'+2=='B'.

I would would not use Unicode in a Vigenere cipher program:  I would use my own encoding in which the first letter of the alphabet is represented by zero, the second letter is represented by one, and so on.  So, for my English example, code('A')==>0, code('B')==>, ... code('Z')==>26.

Then my rotation function looks like this:

```
int rotate(Alphabet alphabet, int code, int amount) {
    return (code + amount) % alphabet.getLength();
}
```

So:

```
rotate(english, code('A'), 2) ==>  (0 + 2)%26 == 2, (the code for 'C'), and
rotate(english, code('Z'), 2) ==> (25 + 2)%26 == 1, (the code for 'B').
```

Comment: Ok, I see.. And if I have english, Russian etc symbols, I need to create alphabet for all of them?

Comment: @Kate21, that's how I would do it.  I'd probably make an `Alphabet` interface with methods to convert between the custom encoding and Unicode, and then I'd make one class that `implements Alphabet` for each language.